# how to set animations for multiple classes(with different ng directives) using JavaScript code(and Velocity)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, velocity, ng-animate

so here's the problem, i'm trying to assign animations with JS at the end of my angular controller in the form below, and the animation should happen when changes occur to the elements. but it seems only the last written animation works (which here, is the one for ng-include element):

```
myModule.animation('.element-With-ng-show', [function () {
return {
    removeClass: function (elem, done) {
        Velocity(elem, 'slideDown', done);
    },
    addClass: function(elem, done){
        Velocity(elem, 'slideUp', done);
    }
}}]);
myModule.animation('.element-with-ng-include', [function () {
return{
    enter: function (elem, done) {
        Velocity(elem, "fadeIn", { delay: 500, duration: 500, display: 'flex' }, done)
    },
    leave: function (elem, done) {
        Velocity(elem, "fadeOut", { duration: 500 }, done)
    }
}}]);
```

how can i make it work??